# Getting undefined when I define {string} parameter in the when section in the step definition in protractor cucumber

Tags: automated-testing, protractor, cucumber, angular

I am new to protractor with cucumber. I have to automate a flow wherein on entering first name, last name, and postcode, a new user is created. I am trying to add the data to be entered in the feature file in examples in the scenario outline as follows:

```
Feature: Demo
            Scenario Outline: Create a customer
                Given I open the application and click on create customer button
                When I enter <firstName>, <lastName>, <postCode>
                Then customer should be created

Examples:
            | firstName | lastName | postCode |
            | Saloni    | Singhal  | 12345  |
            | Harry     | Potter   | 67890  |
```

For the when clause, I added the following code in the step def.:

```
When('I enter {string}, {string}, {int}', async function (string,string,int) {
    browser.sleep(10000);
   await BankManagerButton.click();
    await firstName.sendKeys(string);
    await lastName.sendKeys(string);
    await postCode.sendKeys(int);
    return await addCustButton.click();
    });
```

But on running this one, it gives me error as undefined, and suggest the following:

Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

```
     When('I enter Saloni, Singhal, {int}', function (int) {
     // When('I enter Saloni, Singhal, {float}', function (float) {
       // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
       return 'pending';
     });
```

Comment: when you use float as mentioned , what happens ? . And if it doesn't work, try using string and see whats happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to wrap string with quotes in your feature file,**

**Feature File:**

```
Feature: Demo
            Scenario Outline: Create a customer
                Given I open the application and click on create customer button
                When I enter '<firstName>', '<lastName>', <postCode>
                Then customer should be created

Examples:
            | firstName | lastName | postCode |
            | Saloni    | Singhal  | 12345  |
            | Harry     | Potter   | 67890  |
```

**Also: you need define parameters and not parameter type:**

**Step Definition:**

```
When('I enter {string}, {string}, {int}', async function (a,b,c) {
    browser.sleep(10000);
   await BankManagerButton.click();
    await firstName.sendKeys(a);
    await lastName.sendKeys(b);
    await postCode.sendKeys(c);
    return await addCustButton.click();
    });
```

How will you know what 'string' is passed if you don't give separate name for parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked.. :)